# What happens if function inlining is too aggressive?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, compiler-construction, inline

Each time I read about `inline` keyword in C++ there's a long explanation that the compiler makes a "speed versus code volume" analysis and then decided whether to inline a function call in each specific case.

Now Visual C++ 9 has a [`__forceinline` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx) that seems to make the compiler inline the call to the function unless such inlining is absolutely impossible (like a call is virtual).

Suppose I look through some project without understanding what goes inside it and decide myself that one third of functions are small enough and good for inlining and mark them with `__forceinline` and the compiler does inline them and now the executable has become say one hundred times bigger.

Will it really matter? What effect should I expect from having functions inlined overly aggressively and having one hundred times bigger executable?

Comment: i hear you might stress instruction cache too much

Comment: You might want to look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130248/what-are-good-heuristics-for-inlining-functions/

Comment: `__forceinline` may not always inline something, even where it is possible, this can be due to stack alignment requires, or the inline nesting depth limit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx053bca(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: If you do this, you have violated two tenants of wise optimization.  Don't optimize until you understand the code, and don't optimize until you profile against a repeatable benchmark of the code.  Once you have tools to tell you how much faster it is/isn't, then you can empirically answer a question like this yourself.

Comment: Satan himself will reach up out of the pit to drag you down to hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have already mentioned the impact on cache. There's another penalty to pay. Modern CPU's are quite fast, but at a price. They have deep pipelines of instructions being processed. To keep these pipelines filled even in the presence of conditional branches, fast CPUs use branch prediction. They record how often a branch was taken and use that to predict whether a branch will be taken in the future.

Obviously, this history takes memory, and it's a fixed size table. It contains only a limited number of branch instructions. By increasing the number of instructions a hundredfold, you also increase the number of branches by that much. This means the number of branches with predictions decreases sharply. In addition, for the branches that are present in the prediction table, less data is available.

Answer (score 5):

The main impact will be to the cache. Inlining goes against the principal of locality; the CPU will have to fetch the instructions from the main memory far more often. So what was intended to make the code faster may actually make it slower.

Comment: Why will it have to fetch instructions far more often?

Comment: @zneak: Because the program is bigger, less of it fits in cache at any one moment.

Comment: @zneak I said, "the CPU will have to fetch the instructions **from the main memory** far more often". That's because the instructions won't be in the cache.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos Does it really have that much of an impact? I mean, caches are usually pretty small, and your CPU being multitasking, aren't there pretty good chances that anyways you'll have to fetch often?

Comment: Would be worth listing the principal and how inlining relates to it...?  i.e. "Temporal Locality (locality in time): If an item is referenced, it will tend to be referenced again soon." - but with inlining we're diluting the benefit.

Comment: @zneak: Chip designers don't build caches with the expectation that they won't provide any benefit. They do it fully hoping and expecting to achieve large hit rates on common real-world workloads. Otherwise, why would they bother? So if you take a normal everyday program and balloon it out 100-fold, there's a good chance that your program will run about 100-times more slowly.

Comment: Also note that most systems have a multi-level caching architecture, with L1, L2 and often L3 caches, with each level being slower, but larger, than the previous. Making your program larger across the board compromises every level. Inner loops become bigger, meaning they are less likely to fit in L1, groups of functions that call each other frequently won't fit together in L2, and so on.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos There's no doubt that cache works. In fact, what I doubt is that code size is a serious issue for it. Saying that making code 100 times its original time will make it a hundred times slower is quickly dismissing a lot of facts, and quickly dismissing that C++ tends to be a very real-world case of code that gets huge and yet runs fast.

Comment: Also, any library call is obviously out of cache bounds, and yet programs still heavily rely on them. I know there's a tradeoff between performance and convenience, but to me it looks like it's much less worse than what you're describing. Scattering code across a larger area doesn't invalidate all caches at once, and it's not hard to imagine instruction-fetching algorithms that would work so well for extremely sequential code that I'd be surprised they aren't already implemented in most chips. Do you have any empirical example of a program that's impaired by its size?

Comment: @zneak: I am not dismissing anything; my comments are prefaced with qualifiers like, "there's a good chance...", because I know full well that many, many factors contribute to performance. Also, C++ doesn't "get huge" compared to other languages. There may be some overheads, but they are generally quite modest (usually negligible, in fact) in terms of overall impact to code size.

Comment: @zneak: How did you arrive at the notion that library calls are out of cache bounds? A cache can hold many distinct chunks of memory. If two small pieces of code call each other frequently, they will both be in cache, no matter that one is in the main program and the other in a library "miles" away. If this is your understanding, then I'm not at all surprised that you are struggling to grasp (and demanding empirical evidence) that a 100-fold increase in program size will destroy performance.

Answer (score 3):

It will load and run more slowly, and may run out of virtual address space (100 times bigger is pretty dire).

Answer (score 3):

Having a bigger executable is its own punishment:

1) It takes more memory to store the program which matters more on some systems than others (cell phones for example can have very limited memory)

2) Having a larger program takes longer to load into memory

3) During execution, you will likely have more cache misses (you try to branch to part of your program which isn't in cache) because your program is spread out over more space. This slows down your program.

Answer (score 2):

Less of your program will fit in the CPU caches, disk caches etc. and therefore more time will be wasted as the CPU sits idle waiting for that code to become available.  It's as simple as that really.

Ah - I hadn't looked at who'd posted the question - sharptooth hey ? :-) - you obviously won't have learned anything from the answer above.  But, that's all there is too it - it's just a statistical balancing act, with defaults doubtless shaped by the compiler writers based on customer pressure to explain both larger executable sizes and slower execution speeds when compared to other compiler vendors.

Interesting if dated lectures notes here: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/djimenez/utsa/cs3343/lecture15.html

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat a complex topic, and I think you should have a look at this [C++ faq lite about inline](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.3)

It explains that there is no simple solution, and there are many things to consider (but it all boils down to a good intuition anyway!)